# PCA and diagonalization of the covariance matrix

Tags: self-study, pca

I am preparing for an upcoming exam and having looked at older exams I found one PCA related question I am having trouble understanding:

> You have a dataset of $N$ two-dimensional points $\ y^t $. You want to
>   perform PCA on the dataset. You have already estimated that the data
>   is zero-mean and has the covariance matrix
>
> $$ S = \begin{bmatrix}10 & 6 \\ 6 & 10 \\\end{bmatrix}  $$
>
> and you know that covariance matrix can be diagonalized as $\ C^TSC = D $, where
>
> $$ C = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}  $$ $$ D = \begin{bmatrix}16 & 0 \\0 & 4\end{bmatrix}  $$
>
> - A) Explain how the matrices $C$ and $D$ are related to PCA?
> - B) In
>     2-dimensional space, plot the PCA coordinates (direction of the largest
>     and second largest variance of the data)
> - C) Define the principal
>     components of the data by $z^t=C^Ty^t$. What is the covariance matrix
>     of $z^t$?

I am having trouble understanding how to begin. Matrix $D$ seems to be a diagonalized $S$ (as the diagonal adds up to $20$) but how to perform any calculations on given data I have no clue. What computations should I perform in order to be able to plot the PCA coordinates?

Comment: This is a basic question on the mathematics of PCA. Have you studied any textbooks or tutorials on PCA? Do you know what an eigenvector and an eigenvalue is? Do you know how eigendecomposition is used in PCA?

Comment: @amoeba Basic questions are fine.  If you must question the motivation or background of people who ask them, then please make it clear you are not challenging them but only probing to learn how best to frame a good answer. The issue raised by basic questions, though, is that likely they already are answered here.  I recommend searching our site for related keywords such as "calculate" and "PCA".

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for your comment. I certainly did not mean to say that this question is inappropriate here, and I am sorry if my wording might have suggested it. My point was precisely to find out how much the OP already knows in order to try to give an adequate hint.

Comment: @amoeba thank you for your views. My background is not in mathematics. All the examples I could find assume the knowledge of the subject on deeper level. Especially the study material I have at hand seems more like a course in Greek language.

Comment: :-) I, or somebody else here, would be happy to try to give you a hint, but please tell us if you know what an eigenvector/eigenvalue is.

Comment: Yes I believe I do. Eigenvector is a vector with length of one. It holds the direction of the vector it has been derived from. Am I completely lost?

Comment: Sorry, you did not ping me (type `@amoeba` in your comment to ping), and I haven't noticed your reply before. Anyway, yes, I believe you are quite confused. Here is one [PCA tutorial](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf). It covers math that is really necessary to understand PCA on the first 11 pages; eigenvectors/values are explained on pages 9-11. I will try to make an answer with some hints later on, but in the meantime I would suggest you start reading this (or any other) tutorial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes a bit late, but for any other people looking for a simple intuitive (non-mathematical) idea about PCA: one way to took at it is as follows:

if you have a straight line in 2D, let's say the line y = x. In order to figure out what's happening, you need to keep track of these two directions. However, if you draw it, you can see that actually, there isn't much happening in the direction 45 degrees pointing 'northwest' to 'southeast', and all the change happens in the direction perpendicular to that. This means you actually only need to keep track of one direction: along the line.

This is done by rotating your axes, so that you don't measure along x-direction and y-direction, but along combinations of them, call them x' and y'.

That is exactly encoded in the matrix transformation above: you can see it as a matrix transformation, but equivalently as a rotation of the direction in which you measure. Now I will refer you to maths literature, but do try to think of it as directions in which you measure.